# Why get Unable to verify your data submission error in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

[image]

#### Error:

> Unable to verify your data submission error

Create one public function in Yii2. But, submit data not accept in this method,
see following error images. Why is this happen?

Comment: unable to verify csrf token

Comment: Please share more details about that problem. Is there anything written to your application's log?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add this in the head section of your layout:    `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`

Comment: He is not asking about disabling CSRF.

Comment: As @arogachev already said: It's your comment that is incorrect. The csrf is validated at any time (it not being there also results in failure) unless you turn it off, which was indeed not what was requested.

Comment: Rollback :) Cheers Guys.

Comment: What if I am not using Yii layouts? I'm using angular `$http.put()` and in my controller I have `public $enableCsrfValidation = false;` , this works but not sounds nice.

Comment: this one worked for me
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />

Comment: maybe for somebody it didn't work, since I overlooked it should be <head><meta section, not a form section, furthermore I still had it but my linux browser didn't sent the headers - so I used approach <input type="hidden" name="_frontendCsrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" /> , where name of the csrf param is configured in the settings - components->request-> 'csrfParam' => '_frontendCsrf',

Answer (score 56):

If you create the form manually (i.e. without using the yii form methods), you should add an input field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
```

source: http://zero-exception.blogspot.com/2015/01/yii2-using-csrf-token.html

Comment: Sure, I suppose there are many who create forms manually - thx =)

Comment: had to use as in the settings  `_frontendCsrf` ,  components->request-> 'csrfParam' => '_frontendCsrf',

Answer (score 17):

There are various solutions to this problem, I guess understanding why it happened in the first place helps solve the problem.

1. It is either caused by an invalid csrf token,user generated csrf token, expired csrf token, all these 'csrf' issues will arise when you have custom forms built not using the 'ActiveForm' class.

If CSRF is not the issue,

2. Its other cause occurs when you try to upload multiple files and the web server cannot handle the load. Some properties to check on this to make sure you are on the right track is to claculate the size of files one is attempting to upload and check the web server's post_max_size and upload_max_filesize

If you are running linux, check php.ini file for inputs like these:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data    reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Based on your calculations, adjust the above php.ini parameters to suite your needs, then test.
I had a similar problem and I solved it.

Comment: Thanks It saved my day, Was checking all CSRF issues but it was because of the file upload.

Comment: Happy to have helped

Comment: Happy to have helped, you are allowed to up vote this as the answer. :)

Comment: in my case I am using activeForm and csrf is also getting generated but still getting this error

Comment: @AmosKosgei i have CSRF and i'm not uploading a file. any idea how to resolve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031633/httpexception400-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission?noredirect=1#comment123797970_70031633

Answer (score 7):

To permanently disable csrf validation in whole application add below code in your configurations.

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: And why would you want to disable csrf token validation in a publicly accessible web application?

Comment: just for a work around solution, otherwise I would suggest to keep it enabled else it will be huge security risk

Answer (score 4):

Also sometimes you can get this error using Yii 2.0 due to the **post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_input_time** also too maybe the webserver can be trimming the post so verify on **nginx - client_max_body_size** or in **apache - LimitRequestBody**

Answer (score 4):

Disable for only specific action

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'my-action') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution for when one is accepting posted data from other sites (e.g. payment providers) and the validation is therefore being performed by alternative means - often out of the control of the receiving site/action.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether there is hidden input in your form with CSRF token. It should look like

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="ZEZ6Y0xrY3ARGS42fTwhMQgkDgF6BCEGEx4SMXQMBR4CPy0iPCIwNQ==">
```

Comment: it has one. so now what do i do?

Comment: you can set the value to <?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>

Answer (score 3):

A long story has been discussed here [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4497)

So disabling csrf somehow unsure for ajax request. I have met this issue many times.

So remember to send _csrf key when you send data by POST via ajax.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11531583)

Comment: Thank for your instruct, I will do that if need next time. By the way, in my answer below I gave the correct answer for my situation at the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks you saved me!

Comment: @ThangTD can't just set CSRF in the header using `$.ajaxSetup({});` ?

Answer (score 3):

Updated from yii 2.0.12 to 2.0.30

Have this bad request error 400

- Got the `Html::csrfMetaTags()` in the header layout.
- using activeform,therefore is not caused by missing csrf token in the
     form. And checked already through inspect.

I solved this through adding below code to the `backend/config/main.php`.

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_backend_csrf',
    ],
```

Is it a correct way or will it cause security issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
$csrf = \yii::$app->request->csrfParam;

$token = \yii::$app->request->csrfToken;        

//start from 

echo Html::hiddenInput($csrf,$token);

//end from
```

Comment: also alternative

Answer (score 1):

A little differentiation to dchakarov's answer due to Yii2 tiers using instead of 
`_csrf` variable `_frontendCsrf`.

`<input type="hidden" name="_frontendCsrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />`

This is a second time this question did not help me even though I posted a comment previously, so I have to post a response.

Answer (score 0):

Switched website form https to http and had the issue come up. Updated the request config by commenting the below lines to resolve.

```
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'SomeRandomKeyValidationString',
        //'csrfCookie' => [
        //    'httpOnly' => true,
        //    'secure' => true,
        //],
```

Answer (score -4):

Add this in your **controller**:

```
 public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: Definitely not good advice in my book... Disabling security measures because you can't figure out how they work right away?

Comment: I some cases it maybe needed. For example if you implement Paypal IPN Notifications ...

Comment: Agree, I was trying to implement something similar to IPN notifications so CSRF verification was not an option for this case.

Comment: this is a good answer. disabling CSRF might be necessary in some cases (in mine, to receive facebook POSTs for a webhook)