# Unable to verify your data When I try send a form with Yii2 advance

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

I get this error when I try use some of the forms. (Login or signup). I searched on the web, but I dont see any response (I dont want disable the csrf flag)

In signup form, for example, I send the next data:

```
_csrf:OFNlY3ZOcFdTGR0SNBcfJUAnHTIGeQI0SiZWIjt2HiRqJTUXGiADYg==
SignupForm[username]:test
SignupForm[email]:test@email.com
SignupForm[password]:testtest
signup-button:
```

I see the csrf code in form:

```
<form id="form-signup" action="/apps/dev/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fsignup" method="post" role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="OFNlY3ZOcFdTGR0SNBcfJUAnHTIGeQI0SiZWIjt2HiRqJTUXGiADYg==">
```

Reading, I see also that now Yii2 Template have to add csrf token inside the head tags, I checked it and its here:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="OFNlY3ZOcFdTGR0SNBcfJUAnHTIGeQI0SiZWIjt2HiRqJTUXGiADYg==">
```

Anybody can help me to resolve this problem? Or maybe how I can treat it or found the soulition.

Thanks

Comment: Does it help if you delete cookies? Are you using latest Yii version?

Comment: check this link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459419/why-get-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-error-in-yii2

Comment: Sure, the last version. Fresh install around a week. I already test deleting session, cookies even in other computer and browser.

Comment: show your config file for backend/frontend and what url you hit when you get this error ?

Comment: update yii to 2.10 version and use of this version default config file for requests and sessions.