# yii2 When delete GridView : Unable to verify your data submission

Tags: gridview, yii2, delete-row, behavior

When I want to delete an item on GridView I get this error:

```
exception 'yii\web\BadRequestHttpException' with message 'Unable to verify your data submission.
```

My this my controller code:

```
class DevisController extends Controller
{
 public $layout = 'lay-admin';

 public function behaviors()
 {
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
/* ..... */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

And when I change the post method to the get method  in behaviors function I get this error

```
Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET.
```

GridView code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    //'idDevis',
                    'reference',
                    'client',
                    'dateCreation',
                    'contact',
                    'valableJusqua',
                    'dateRelance',
                    [
                     'attribute'=>'etat',
                     'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Devis::find()->asArray()->all(), 'etat', 'etat'),
                    ],
                    'commercial',
                    'modePaiement',
                    'delaiPaiement',

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                ],
]); ?>
```

any idea please!!

Comment: Is CSRF parameter present in your view?

Comment: I don't think, I can't see this parameter

Comment: now I get this error `Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.`

Comment: Paste the code of your gridview in question.

Comment: ok I will update my question

Comment: Have you got `Html::csrfMetaTags()` in your `lay-admin` layout file?

Comment: no, i havn't this function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why get Unable to verify your data submission error in Yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459419/why-get-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-error-in-yii2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CSRF meta tag in your custom layout file.

Example:

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>

    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
```

[Here you can read more about CSRF](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html#avoiding-csrf).

Comment: What if I have csrf but still get `bad request 400` on delete ?