# Button click yii2

Tags: yii2

I have this button in view:
`<button name="render_button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary'  style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render </button><br>`
How to set up call `actionIndex` with certain function, for example, if `button_1` is clicked then call `actionIndex` with `getSome();`, like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if(isset($_POST['render_button'])) {
        $data = order::getSome();
    }

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data,
        'sort' => [
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an initial value to the `$data` variable, a value like `null` and then pass it to the `$dataProvider` array like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $data = null;
    if(isset($_POST['render_button'])) {
        $data = order::getSome();
    }

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data,
        'sort' => [
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
        'data' => $data
    ]);

    return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);
}
```

Now, inside your view, you just check whenever the `$data` variable is `null` or else you get the trigger and have `order::getSome()` data strored in the `$data` variable.

**EDIT**

Didn't see you are passing the `$data` variable to the `allModels` item, but it's the same. Just check the `allModels` inside your view whenever it's set to `null` or it has some data.

**UPDATE**

Update your view `index.php` to have a post form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="render_button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render </button><br>
</form>
```

Comment: It does not handle the button click in controller. For example `if(isset($_POST['render_button'])) {
            actionIndex();
        }` there is no refresh page.

Comment: You need to have a form or to post/get with AJAX. Can you update with the full HTML code containing the button?

Comment: I have only this `<button name="render_button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary'  style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render </button><br>` in view(index.php)

Comment: Try to add a form and make the button to be of a submit type. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: It's best to use a form @stand. A button will always initiate a `GET` request unless instructed otherwise

Comment: @Yasky I don't think a button initiates a `GET` request without a form. It just triggers the `DOM` `click` event.

Comment: @Christos Lytras I add form with button, there is work. And add your actionIndex();(without `'data' => $data`). But when I click, there is error `Unable to verify your data submission.`What can be wrong? Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @stand add this in the head section of your layout: `<?php echo Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`. See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28690225/1889685