# yii2 :what is this error Bad Request (#400) in (delete every thing and sign up)

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

my site is correct in localhost but when my site uplaoded in host has this error :There was an error with your request.Bad Request (#400)

i have error in delete every thing and create user in rbac and signup user!

i used : rback and dekturim users in yii2!

image description here :
[image]

my log after 400# bad request  is :

```
2017-08-19 11:28:02 [84.241.12.226][-][b96a8346d2481cedc6735e51e3b61c1e][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: قادر به تأیید اطلاعات ارسالی شما نمی‌باشد. in /home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:166 Stack trace:
#0 /home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(154): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 /home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('register', Array)
#2 /home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('user/registrati...', Array)
#3 /home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#4 /home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main} 2017-08-19 11:28:02 [84.241.12.226][-][b96a8346d2481cedc6735e51e3b61c1e][info][application] $_POST = [
    '_csrf' => '4KoJ9MNFGxzQbb4V5iikZ9bdtKiPh5Ee3X2dx3Rr5ye18xSbfRJI1enAWEhLN4TgJRY9LiZyOPEaxkcB23vXEw=='
    'register-form' => [
        'email' => 'asda@asd.com'
        'username' => 'sdadadadasd'
        'password' => ''
    ]
    'ajax' => 'registration-form' ]

$_COOKIE = [
    'PHPSESSID' => 'b96a8346d2481cedc6735e51e3b61c1e'
    '_csrf' => '9611e96b8f955e10840fcbad09d2104200ba70bf1b3729fbf78e3523cf4ca777a:2:{i:0;s:5:\"_csrf\";i:1;s:32:\"����!7c?�m�\'��\"��3�i�Z�b(�^�]��\";}' ]

$_SESSION = [
    '__flash' => []
    '__returnUrl' => '/newadmin/web/index.php/user/admin/create' ]

$_SERVER = [
    'PATH' => '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive'
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '329'
    'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'PHPSESSID=b96a8346d2481cedc6735e51e3b61c1e; _csrf=9611e96b8f955e10840fcbad09d2104200ba70bf1b3729fbf78e3523cf4ca777a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22%A4%B9%F3%FB%217c%3F%F3m%CC%27%AE%CA%22%99%AD3%DD%0Bi%A4Z%A0b%28%D1%5E%AD%5D%B5%E3%22%3B%7D'
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'niniplus.com'
    'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://niniplus.com/newadmin/web/index.php/user/register'
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0 FirePHP/0.7.4'
    'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0'
    'HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN' => '4KoJ9MNFGxzQbb4V5iikZ9bdtKiPh5Ee3X2dx3Rr5ye18xSbfRJI1enAWEhLN4TgJRY9LiZyOPEaxkcB23vXEw=='
    'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
    'HTTP_DNT' => '1'
    'HTTP_X_INSIGHT' => 'activate'
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home/niniplus/public_html'
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => '84.241.12.226'
    'REMOTE_PORT' => '22220'
    'SERVER_ADDR' => '185.88.153.190'
    'SERVER_NAME' => 'niniplus.com'
    'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'webmaster@niniplus.com'
    'SERVER_PORT' => '80'
    'REQUEST_URI' => '/newadmin/web/index.php/user/register'
    'PATH_TRANSLATED' => '/home/niniplus/public_html/user/register'
    'PATH_INFO' => '/user/register'
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/home/niniplus/public_html/newadmin/web/index.php'
    'QUERY_STRING' => ''
    'SCRIPT_URI' => 'http://niniplus.com/newadmin/web/index.php/user/register'
    'SCRIPT_URL' => '/newadmin/web/index.php/user/register'
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/newadmin/web/index.php'
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1'
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'LiteSpeed'
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST'
    'X-LSCACHE' => 'on'
    'PHP_SELF' => '/newadmin/web/index.php/user/register'
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1503125882.5156
    'REQUEST_TIME' => 1503125882 ]
```

Comment: Did you map the path correctly to /web?

Comment: which  OS your are using in localhost and in host  ..?  .. and please update your question with  the error messagge too

Comment: @cbaconnier yes! my project in /web !

Comment: What's the error in the log file?

Comment: "قادر به تأیید اطلاعات ارسالی شما نمی‌باشد" I'm guessing the error means "unable to verify your data submission" which is apparently related to an error of csrf validation. What if you clear your cookies for this domain, reload the page and then submit your form ?

Comment: public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

when i added this function in controller my error solved !

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution though. You're opening your website to vulnerbilities by doing that. Instead, [what if you add this in the head section of your layout:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690225/8068675)  `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`

Comment: how  can add this code in  delete action in  (ajax crud )  ???

Comment: or in signup yii2 users dekturim work is correct for another people and another server!

Comment: `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` will automatically add the csrf to every post / get requests whether it is ajax or not

Comment: i check post in firebug and taht is blank  ! 
reponse has  bad request and post is blank ! :-( why?

Comment: I have this problem too. Did your problem solved?

Comment: any solution? i'm not getting a 400 when i use my forms, but my log files shows some users are. why?