# Unable to verify your data submission on forms

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, yii, yii2

I'm getting alot of these types of errors in my log files

```
2021-10-17 15:06:39 [60.54.140.90][1550][sf4vnas08uip2fd2avrqkdstd0][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data submission. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(179): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#4 /var/www/html/frontend/web/index.php(64): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
2021-10-17 15:06:39 [60.54.140.90][1550][sf4vnas08uip2fd2avrqkdstd0][info][application] $_GET = []

$_POST = [
    '_csrf-frontend' => 'p3KtJP4UdPnnct2Nry4rEwBu1OxElrwqIAkYttxytW7AF-hIz0IZwd4tvuz5TXJBVByduiz810tOMVz8txjGFw=='
    'LoginForm' => [
        'login' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
        'password' => 'xxx1239836'
        'rememberMe' => '1'
    ]
    'ajax' => 'LoginForm'
]
```

in my `main.php`

```
    'request' => [
        'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        'enableCookieValidation' => true,
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'blabla-2021',
        'csrfCookie'=> [
            'httpOnly'=>true,
        ],
    ],
```

i do have this in my header `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` and i don't create forms manually.

Forms work fine when i test them on localhost and live too.

Any idea why i'm getting this? and how to fix it? Thanks

**UPDATE**

updated my `main.php` to this, but still getting the same errors

```
'request' => [
            'enableCsrfCookie' => false, //force application to store the CSRF token in session instead of cookie
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        ],
```

Comment: Look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459419/why-get-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-error-in-yii2

Comment: @HaimEvgi i did, i already have `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` and i'm not uploading multiple files.

Comment: Your cookie appears to be set to 'httpOnly' but the request type appears to be made through javascript (i.e ajax) which means js wont have access to the cookie. You might want to make the csrf cookie available to js in that case

Comment: @Sherif do i remove `$csrfCookie` all together? or is there away to allow javascript / ajax posts to access the cookies too?

Comment: You could try setting __httpOnly__ to false.

Comment: @Sherif thanks, in the docs it says setting `enableCsrfCookie` to false would use session. would that be a better solution and work for both http and javascript? even though it might slow down the site a bit?

Comment: The session should not have the httpOnly param by default, so yes it should qork. Not sure why you think it might slow down thw site though.

Comment: @Sherif thank you, will try and it monitor the logs. About the site performance, i read it here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$enableCsrfCookie-detail

Comment: @Sherif still getting the same errors, updated question.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the cookie and reset the session storage?

Answer (score 0):

Set `$enableCsrfValidation = false` in your web controllers: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/d80974da3097b844e60398bea797d6226a0e12d1/framework/web/Controller.php#L32